# Correcting live IMFMediaSource time stamps

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, video, ms-media-foundation

I have two cameras, listed below, that I am trying to use in a Media Foundation topology. Here is a summary of my topology:

Webcam --> MJPG Decoder --> Custom MFT --> H264 Encoder --> MP4 File Sink

The problem with this is that the generated MP4 file has incorrect duration and time scale tags, both for the MP4 container and the H264 stream.  I can easily correct this with a tool like MP4Box or YAMB, but my eventual goal is to stream the video.

One potential cause I have identified is that the samples generated by the camera sources do not start at time 0. According to bullet #2 in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms700134(v=vs.85).aspx#live_sources, timestamps of a live source should start at 0.

Along this line, I've tried the following to "correct" the sample timestamps:

1. Re-based the sample time in my custom MFT, using `IMFSample::SetSampleTime`.
2. Created a wrapper for the IMFMediaSource and IMFMediaStream objects, which catches and corrects the time stamps associated with the `MEMediaSample` and `MEStreamTick` events.

In both of these cases, the media session throws an error `0xC00D4A44` (`MF_E_SINK_NO_SAMPLES_PROCESSED`), and the resulting MP4 file ends abruptly after the "mdat" atom declaration.

---

Cameras

- Logitech BCC950 ConferenceCam
- Thinkpad W520 Integrated Camera

---

Systems used (both have same issue):

- Windows 7 Professional x64
- Windows 8 x86

---

Questions:

1. **Is there some other cause I have overlooked for incorrect video duration/time scale?**
2. **If not, is there a correct approach for how to re-base sample timestamps?**

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset for every sample flag MFSampleExtension_Discontinuity

```
pSample->SetUINT32( MFSampleExtension_Discontinuity, FALSE );
```